# Django images don't load through the admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I've never had such a problem , but images that I upload via the admin panel are no longer saved.
After creating an item , the image is not saved to the folder.

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('news/', include('news.urls', namespace="news")),
    path('service/', include('service.urls', namespace="service")),
    path('', include('slide.urls', namespace="slide")),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'
MEDIA_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

**models.py**

```
class Slide(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=130)
    description = models.TextField("Text")
    image = models.ImageField('image', upload_to='')
    url = models.CharField("url", max_length=130, blank=True)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

replace:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'
MEDIA_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

with:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

for static:

````
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files') # here ```static_files``` can be any name.
````

Doc is here for [for Django3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/) and [for Django2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/).
Django3 is using `path` rather than `os`.
Here is for Django3.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR.joinpath('static_files')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR.joinpath('media')
```